# Migrating Plastic SCM from SQLite to MSSQL Server backend

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, migration, plasticscm

There is Plastic SCM Server 6.0.16.1765 installed on the development server (MS Windows) with SQLite backend. It needs to migrate the existing repositories to MSSQL Server backend, but something goes wrong.
I followed the [instruction](https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/administration/plastic-scm-version-control-administrator-guide.shtml#ConfigurePlasticSCMwithSQLServer)  step-by-step and it ends up with the error message(at step 7):

> The migration progress has failed: The database repositories can't be created. Check the server log (plastic.server.log). Error: Directory lookup for the file "c:\program files\plasticscm5\server\repositories.plastic" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.). CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

I checked as suggested (the server log) and it has the same message as above.
There's no ***c:\program files\plasticscm5\server\repositories.plastic*** file or catalog at server - it's true. SQLite data files are located on different place. Why does the *plastic migrator* check this path?

The repository storage connection is configured using integrated security:

> Data Source=MSSQL_SERVER\INSTANCE;Integrated Security=SSPI;DATABASE={0};

Note: the SQLite data files have the extension **.sqlite**, so it will never find the **repositories.plastic** file.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue with the last 7.0.16.1944 server version. I've tested using the webadmin to perform the migration and also with the .sqlite  databases stored in a custom location: http://blog.plasticscm.com/2017/10/webadmin-introducing-new-server-admin.html

Comment: By the way, don't yo consider migrating to our new file based database system: Jet? It's the current default database and our recommended option in terms of performance: https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/administration/plastic-scm-version-control-administrator-guide.shtml#ConfigurePlasticSCMwithJet

Comment: Ok, but the latest stable version is 6.0.16.1765. Is it possible on/off detailed logging?

Comment: 7.x version is not operable on my installation, because it cannot be run using 6.x server licence

Comment: Jet backend is not acceptable because: 1. it would be impossible to migrate to another backend, it is not supported (one way ticket); 2. database storage is preferable because it is esier to support

Answer (score 0):

After spending some hours, it was found that the problem is in **optional** parameter **Database path**. Actually, the parameter must be mandaroty in case of MSSQL Server backend. Neither migration wizard nor the error message gave anything can help. The migration log is missing.